# Cordova in VIsual studio: How to use local plugin

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing a Cordova hybrid app, i need to add a plugin to enable the app to run in background so I'm using the plugin downloaded from here:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

I had downloaded the entire source code in zip and import into my Visual Studio Plugins folder just like below:

[image]

And in my project properties, i can see the plugin but the on/off button is gray off. I'm not sure if this means anything thou.

[image]

But i do not know how to call the code now. According to the documentation, i can enable the background plugin with `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();`, but when I do that I got the "backgroundMode is not defined" error. It's the same when I tried `navigator.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();`

Please let me know if there is additional steps that I had missed before I can call the code. Thanks

Comment: Did you reference the plugin in config.xml? Which Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I added `<feature name="BackgroundMode"><param name="ios-package" value="APPBackgroundMode" /></feature>` into the iOS config.xml and then tried `cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();` but still doesn't work. I tried `console.log(navigator.plugins);` but doesn't have the plugin name in it. I'm using Visual studio 2015 Community Cordova version 4.0

Comment: if you added this plugin into your project, there should be a plugin tag for this plugin: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" version="0.6.6-dev" src="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git" />` in config.xml.

Comment: I don't see the tag in my config.xml. Even if I add it in manually, i still couldn't call the BackgroundMode plugin. Any tips on what had I missed?